# Sony SDK for control from custom windows program via USB?

Tags: sdk, usb, sony

I am wondering if the Sony SDK may be used to develop a Windows OS based program to trigger Sony A6300 cameras and collect images via the USB port?  We need to trigger several cameras simultaneously based on GPS time and then timestamp the images.  We would collect GPS times from a standalone GPS receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sony Camera Remote API SDK to developer for the A6300 on any platform including Windows.  For more info see:
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

However, the API only works over a direct WiFi connection, not over USB.

Comment: Yes I have looked at that SDK. I reason that since the Sony Camera Remote Control windows program that comes with the camera does in fact control the camera over USB alone, it must be possible. Is there no programming assistance in this regard?

A non-wired connection will not be possible for our purposes. I see a lot of the same questions being asked in this regard.

Is the code for the Camera Remote Control program available for reference, or re-purpose?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately the code for that program is not open source or distributed.  At this time the only way to programmatically control the camera is via WiFi.